# Migrate SO questions here and close as duplicate or close at SO?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

[How to permanently delete a row in oracle forever](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40271/how-to-permanently-delete-a-row-in-oracle-forever)

This question prior to being migrated to dba.se already had a comment that it was *previously answered* on dba.se, with a link.  However, the close brigade continued to migrate it over to DBA.SE, and I then flagged it for closing as a duplicate of

[forensically deleting/updating data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12958/forensically-deleting-updating-data)

Even if this isn't eventually closed as a duplicate, I wonder what the consensus is here or on StackOverflow, where the question originated, on moving duplicate questions.

Comment: Note that questions >60 days old can't be migrated regardless. If it isn't getting answers on one site but has answers on another, just have those mods close and/or delete the iteration that is languishing.

Comment: And reference the stronger one in the close request