# Should one open a new question on DBA if a similar question exists on SO which cannot be migrated?

Tags: discussion, migration

I was about to ask about AWS migration, but [found it addressed on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38331599/increasing-the-storage-of-an-existing-sql-server-rds-instance-on-aws).  That question is more than 60 days old, and therefore it can't be migrated (I believe).  Still, it's a DBA-related question, and the answer may change as Amazon adds capabilities.  It would be valuable to have it - or a copy of it - here.

In such circumstances, should one create a new question on DBA.SE, assuming that the SO question cannot be migrated?

Related: [Migrate SO questions here and close as duplicate or close at SO?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/migrate-so-questions-here-and-close-as-duplicate-or-close-at-so)

Answer (score 6):

My opinion, we should create new questions on DBA.SE. There are a many good questions and answers over there that just seem like a better fit here. It would help when people are searching the site and make the related & linked questions better.

It's interesting to see how there are some really good questions on SO from before 2012 relating to DB stuff. Then it all seems to die out and become DBA questions.

Comment: ...and/or make the Q & A Community Wiki when it has been copied to DBA.SE

Answer (score 2):

If the question you propose is identical to the one answered on Stack Overflow and that question has excellent answers that are up-to-date and helpful, I'd probably lean towards [not duplicating (cross-posting) the post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).

If the question is of poor quality, or the answers are out of date on Stack Overflow , I'd probably vote-to-close the question on Stack Overflow , then post my version of the question here with the intent of getting good, helpful, answers.

Having multiple copies of a question on multiple sites can only cause confusion for the future reader.